# Ajax post request results with 400 error in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, post, http-status-code-400

I'm currently developing a plugin. In the plugin's `main.php` file, I have the following code to do an ajax post request:

`main.php`

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'first_ajax' );

function first_ajax() { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#mybutton').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action : 'second_ajax'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("successful");
            },
            error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

But on the browser console, I see an error object.

| Screenshot 1 | Screenshot 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: console error-upside] | [image: console error-downside] |

I wrote this function taking as reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling javascript from a php function tho your javascript is "raw" and not wrapped in a php variable. We're also missing a bunch of information in regard to the ajax action function (the php part which is supposed to answer to the request).

An ajax request need two things to be able to work properly.

The javascript call to action function and the backend php action function.

It a standard to use [anonymous php functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) as action functions.

Ajax action functions hooks are prepended with a [`wp_ajax_{$action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/) for public function (non-logged-in users) and [`wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/) for logged-in users. A logged-in user won't be able to use a public ajax function same goes for non-logged-in users.

The `{$action}` part is set in your javascript call to action function.

It is standard to pass a [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) as well as the ajax admin url through the [`localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) function. Localizing data only works if the script has already been registered.

An example of registering/[enqueuing](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) a script and localizing varaibles: `functions.php`

```
<?php

wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-script', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'assets/js/my-ajax-script.js', array(), wp_get_theme()->version, true );

wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-script', 'localize', array(
    '_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    '_ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( '_ajax_nonce' ),
) );
```

(The Object's name `localize` and variables `_ajax_url` and `_ajax_nonce` used in [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) are just a personal preference).

---

A basic javascrip ajax call to action function looks like this: `my-ajax-script.js`

```
$( '#selector' ).click( function ( event ) {
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: localize._ajax_url,
        context: this,
        data: {
            _ajax_nonce: localize._ajax_nonce,
            action: '_wpso_73933867', //where this match {$action} from wp_ajax_{$action} in our php action function. 
        },
        success: function ( response ) {
            console.log( response );
            //...
        },
    } );
} );
```

Where we use are localized variables: `localize._ajax_url` and `localize._ajax_nonce` (best practices).

---

A basic php ajax action function looks like this: `functions.php`

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax__wpso_73933867', function () {

    if ( check_ajax_referer( '_ajax_nonce' ) ) {

        //...

        wp_send_json_success();

    } else {
        
        //...

        wp_send_json_error();

    };

    wp_die();

} );
```

If the function is intended to be use by a non-logged-in user `wp_ajax_nopriv` should be prepended instead of `wp_ajax_`. Vice versa. If both case are supposed to be used, the function should be doubled.